# How to check if text editor view in Visual Studio is modified (unsaved)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mef

In order to trigger autocompletion I need to know which text view among opened ones does contain modified text (i.e. not yet saved to disk). How can I check that having IVsTextView and ITextView instances?

Comment: And what your code looks like? Do you use any framework for text editor or is it your code?

Comment: I use MEF (the official framework from MS for writing extensions for Visual Studio).

Comment: So show us your code so we can help you out. Without seeing your code I can tell you that you can use communication between your modules(plugins) with `Publish–subscribe pattern`. Frameworks such as `Prism` and `Caliburn.Micro` provide this functionality, but it's easy to write it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the following solution:

```
IVsTextLines buffer;
if (vsTextView.GetBuffer(out buffer) != VSConstants.S_OK)
{
    return false;
}

uint flags;
buffer.GetStateFlags(out flags);
bool isDirty = (flags & (uint)BUFFERSTATEFLAGS.BSF_MODIFIED) != 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If text view is based on a document, you can use [IVsRunningDocumentTable3.IsDocumentDirty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsrunningdocumenttable3.isdocumentdirty.aspx) method.